# AUC by trapezoid method in R

Tags: r, auc

I'm a beginner who just started using R.

I am trying to obtain the AUC for each time section using the trapezoid method with the results measured at 0,10,20,30,40, 50, 60 minutes for each ID.
What should I do?

```
  CASET0    T10 T20 T30 T40 T50 T60
1     88    89  91  105 107 139 159
2     92    NA  102 NA  NA  189 144
3     79    NA  82  98  106 140 118
5     81    81  82  92  86  101 124
8     90    89  89  106 115 134 101
9     91    77  87  82  95  133 156
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  You'll tend to get better answers if you can be more specific about your question.  See the guidance about minimal reproducible examples https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.  It also helps to include what have you tried, what you are getting, and what output are you expecting

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach with `dplyr` and `caTools::trapz`:

First, we need to get the times, which are currently stuck in the column names. We can use `readr::parse_number` for convenience:

```
readr::parse_number(names(data))
[1]  0 10 20 30 40 50 60
```

From there, we can use `caTools::trapz`. It takes two arguments, `x` and `y`. We can use `dplyr` to apply the function to the whole row with `rowwise` and `c_across`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(caTools)
data %>% 
   rowwise() %>%
   mutate(AUC = trapz(parse_number(names(cur_data())),c_across()))
# Rowwise: 
  CASET0   T10   T20   T30   T40   T50   T60   AUC
   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl>
1     88    89    91   105   107   139   159  6545
2     92    NA   102    NA    NA   189   144    NA
3     79    NA    82    98   106   140   118    NA
4     81    81    82    92    86   101   124  5445
5     90    89    89   106   115   134   101  6285
6     91    77    87    82    95   133   156  5975
```

Or dealing with NAs:

```
data %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(AUC = trapz(parse_number(names(cur_data()))[!is.na(c_across())],
                     c_across()[!is.na(c_across())]))
# Rowwise: 
  CASET0   T10   T20   T30   T40   T50   T60   AUC
   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl>
1     88    89    91   105   107   139   159  6545
2     92    NA   102    NA    NA   189   144  7970
3     79    NA    82    98   106   140   118  6050
4     81    81    82    92    86   101   124  5445
5     90    89    89   106   115   134   101  6285
6     91    77    87    82    95   133   156  5975
```

See the [dplyr rowwise tutorial](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/04/dplyr-1-0-0-rowwise/) for more hints.

---

Alternatively, you might use a base R approach with `apply`:

```
apply(data,1,function(x) trapz(as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9]+","",names(data)))[!is.na(x)],
                               x[!is.na(x)]))
   1    2    3    5    8    9 
6545 7970 6050 5445 6285 5975
```

Data:

```
data <- structure(list(CASET0 = c(88L, 92L, 79L, 81L, 90L, 91L), T10 = c(89L, 
NA, NA, 81L, 89L, 77L), T20 = c(91L, 102L, 82L, 82L, 89L, 87L
), T30 = c(105L, NA, 98L, 92L, 106L, 82L), T40 = c(107L, NA, 
106L, 86L, 115L, 95L), T50 = c(139L, 189L, 140L, 101L, 134L, 
133L), T60 = c(159L, 144L, 118L, 124L, 101L, 156L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "5", "8", "9"))
```